# shallow render styled components with css and snapshot testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot-testing

I'm using styled components and jest+enzyme+jest-styled-components to test my components.
I want to be able to **shallow** render components and use snapshot testing:

```
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyStyledComponent someProp>ASDF</MyStyledComponent>);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

The resulting snapshot is:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`default 1`] = `
<ComponentStyles__MyStyledComponent>
  <ComponentStyles_Bla>
    ASDF
  </ComponentStyles_Bla>
</ComponentStyles__MyStyledComponent>
```

The problem is that the styling is not included.
What i'm trying to reach is that my snapshots include the actual css of the styled component.
Using enzyme's `mount` I was able to see the css nicely in the snapshot:

```
exports[`style2 1`] = `
.c0 {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
}

<div
  className="c0"
>
  ...
</div>
`;
```

But it's important for me to render **shallow** only, and when I use `shallow` I see only the component without the css (as above).

Also tried with enzyme's `dive` method without success.
So, is there any way to shallow render a styled component and get the css in the snapshot?

Comment: Could this help https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/145#issuecomment-394927582 ?

Comment: the issue is regarding deep rendering. I'm trying to do it with shallow rendering.